# SAP Background Job: how is it running?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sap-basis

I have to move an SAP background job (ABAP report for A/P) into Cronacle and can't figure out how to stop the job in SAP so I can start running it with the Cronacle schedule.

The job runs in SAP from user SAPSYS every morning at 7:15am, but if you look it up with `SM37`, there is no time scheduled for it and it's not triggered by an event; also, its status is SCHEDULED.

I had our Cronacle team search by job number but they couldn't find any scripts pointing to that job.  If you look at the finished job it shows that it's scheduled daily for 7:15am.  Also, there is no predecessor or successor jobs listed.

Is it possible that it's being started from another job?  How do I find out without deleting this one?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestion.

1. If you don't want to delete the scheduled job. try to rename it, and see if it still runs.
2. Make sure that the users you are using for sm37 has full authorization for the backround administration.
3. A previous job can schedule and release and create and whatever a new job. Look at what is running before the problematic job.
4. Look deeply at the dev traces. They somtimes hints about what is going on in the system.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to a previous job creating the new job explicitly it is also possible that the job is created manually by an ABAP program that is scheduled in another job.  Doing a where-used on the function module OPEN_JOB and looking for Z* or Y* programs may give you a hint.

Another thing:  Is this scheduled job ever actually excecuted (i.e. are there any previous "FINISHED" jobs with the same name).  A Scheduled job will not run unless it is first released.  So if it never runs it may be obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses!  It turned out to be a case of "newbie ignorance."  When using SM37 to view the job I neglected to extend the search date to the next day.  I don't know why it doesn't show the released job for the current day, but extending it to the next day showed it.  That's a lesson I won't forget!